# Globar var value undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, google-maps-api-3

I can not find the solution to this problem, I need to get on global haight var the value that returns function **success**.

In the alerts,  **alert("inside function" + haight)** the value it's ok but in the other alert, **alert("outside function" + haight);** the value is undefined.

Any suggestion?

```
<script type="text/javascript">


     var haight;

                var options = {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true, 
                    timeout: 5000, 
                    maximumAge: 0 
                };

                function success(pos) { 
                    var crd = pos.coords;
                    haight = new google.maps.LatLng(crd.latitude, crd.longitude);
                    alert("inside function" + haight);

                }
                ;
                function error(err) {
                    console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
                }
                ;
                alert("outside funtcion" + haight);
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

            </script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
alert("outside funtcion" + haight);
```

first call navigator function then call alert.

Comment: If I put the alert after, the alert inside the function not display